No matching variant for sqldelight android driver in KMM
I'm encountering a build error when using a custom build type ("snapshot") in my KMM (Kotlin Multiplatform Mobile) project with SQLDelight. The debug build works perfectly fine, but the snapshot build throws an error:
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':android:app:snapshotRuntimeClasspath'.
Could not resolve app.cash.sqldelight:android-driver:2.0.0.
Required by:
project :android:app
project :android:app > project :kmp:shared > project :kmp:core-db

> No matching variant of app.cash.sqldelight:android-driver:2.0.0 was found.

Here's my KMM source sets configuration:
kotlin {
  sourceSets {
    commonMain.dependencies {
      implementation(project(":kmp:core"))
      implementation(project(":kmp:core-api"))
      implementation(libs.sqldelight.runtime)
      implementation(libs.korlibs.klock)
      api(libs.sqldelight.flow.ext)
      api(libs.sqldelight.primitive.adapters)
    }

    androidMain.dependencies {
      implementation(libs.sqldelight.android.driver)
    }

    iosMain.dependencies {
      implementation(libs.sqldelight.native.driver)
    }
  }
}

I've tried the following but haven't found a solution:
buildTypes {
        getByName("snapshot"){
            initWith(getByName("release"))
            matchingFallbacks.addAll(listOf("debug, release"))
        }
    }
   


Did you try it with the current version 2.0.2?

@mipa thanks for your comment, yes I did try, receiving the same error
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.component.NoMatchingConfigurationSelectionException: No matching variant of app.cash.sqldelight:android-driver:2.0.2 was found. The consumer was configured to find a library for use during runtime, preferably optimized for Android, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'snapshot', attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr' with value '8.2.2', attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm' but:

do you have repositories {   google()   mavenCentral() }?

yes @PhilDukhov I do have that, that's why my debug variants are working, but not the custom variant snapshot

I think your matchingFallbacks syntax is wrong. Try changing it to matchingFallbacks.addAll(listOf("debug", "release"))

You are quite close with matchingFallbacks here. I have the same problem and we have a multimodule project.
This article points that you need to specify matchingFallbacks for "snapshot" build type of every module. In our case it solved the problem.
